# how to run antlr4ruby script on windows

Tags: ruby, antlr

Following the guide http://antlr.ohboyohboyohboy.org/GettingStarted.html,when run in windows doc environment ,it suggest me that "antlr4ruby" not a valid command,how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Ruby target for ANTLR 4. The target you have referenced is for ANTLR 3 (i.e. the command would be `antlr3ruby`, not `antlr4ruby`).

Comment: Thanks,following the tutorials http://antlr.ohboyohboyohboy.org/GettingStarted.html,I've already success finishing that,and the command antlr4ruby is right,here 4 means 'for' I think